# Baking in oven after machine kneading

Tags: baking

I want to remove the bread after it is kneaded and then bake it in the oven. When will I know that it is fully kneaded? I have a rosewill 2 pound bread maker

Comment: Does the machine have a mode that it just mixes and raise the dough ?

Answer (score 1):

Well-kneaded dough should be smooth and supple.  Once you have experience, you can usually tell by the feel of the dough.

Sometimes the "skin" of the dough breaks over the surface; this also indicates that you're done kneading.

The classic test is to poke the dough with your finger: if it springs back, it's been kneaded enough.

(Incidentally, the way you know the dough is finished rising is that it *doesn't* spring back when you poke it).

Comment: Do you mean the OP should be stopping the machine and opening it to feel it multiple times? If it works, it sounds inconvenient. It is also possible that it doesn't work, if either the OP misjudges the state of the dough or the machine's timing and does not take it out before the baking stage has started, or if the machine's programming doesn't allow re-assumption of the process after interruption. It is so cumbersome, it negates the whole point of using a machine (which is to delegate the work while you are busy with something else).

Answer (score 1):

Is [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B018H1YPFY) your machine? If so, the manual is vague on the subject of a dough cycle. However, on the Amazon page, you can see that the dough cycle is number 8 if you use the magnification feature on the metallic plaque around the digital display. That's the cycle you want to use. When it signals that it's done, deflate the dough gently and shape it into the loaf you want to bake. Let it do its second rise. Bake in the oven.

The advice in @Superwild1's answer is spot-on if you can and want to physically check the dough before it starts its first rise. But a big part of the point of a breadmaker is that you shouldn't *have* to.